# Pressing v key enters CTRL-V and vice versa in Windows 8

Tags: keyboard-layout, windows-8

As it says above, I've just installed Windows 8 Pro on a workstation. I've started re-installing all my usual software.

There isn't that much typing required to install software, so I've only recently become aware that when I type V (into any application as far as I can tell), it types CTRL-V. And CTRL-V enters v, Shift-V is as expected.

I normally use a Logitech G11 keyboard, but I have a spare Microsoft keyboard which produces the same results.

No idea why/how this came about.... any ideas?

Is there a way to remap an individual key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured out the answer... I use a nifty little app called Puretext, which usually was mapped to Win+V.

Under Windows 8, [you can't map it to Win+V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767458/how-do-you-register-a-custom-winv-hotkey-on-windows-8), so in my case, it had ignored the Win and just looked for the V. Every time I pressed V, Puretext was pasting a text-only version of whatever was in the clipboard.

I'm not sure what I'm going to to without my Win+V Puretext shortcut, but it's got to go...

**Jan '13 Update:**
I initially jumped to a puretext clone, called Plaintexter - this still worked under Windows 8, for which I'll be eternally grateful. However, I contacted Steve Miller (who explained the changes under Win 8 that caused problems) and he said that he'd Win-8-ify PureText in due course.

Steve contacted recently - an updated version of [Puretext](http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/) is now available. I'm happily jumped ship, back to Puretext - it's more responsive than Plaintexter, enough to make the transition worthwhile.

Comment: CJM: A year ago, you "committed" to help start a Genealogy Q&A site at Area51. That one did not succeed to Beta. We've started a new one up with more momentum and now only need 25 more Committers with 200+ rep to get to Beta. Hopefully you're still interested and will Commit again to help it. Sorry to leave this comment here, but it was the only way I could contact you. The Genealogy proposal is at: http://bit.ly/U3vnDX

Answer (score 1):

The most common bit of advice in this case is, "Press both the left and right CTRL keys at the same time."  The theory is that is has to do with nascent "accessibility" settings.

I stumbled upon a more in-depth discussion of similar problems while searching troubleshooting a wireless keyboard/trackpad combo: http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=729744

Comment: Thanks for the effort - I should have made it clear that it was only the V key that was a problem and not any other combinations.